# Optimistic concurrency with MVC4 ApiController

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have an MVC 4 hybrid SPA (each function is an SPA, but navigating between functions re-loads the page) created with Visual Studio 2012 in which I intend to rely on Entity Framework and optimistic concurrency (although updates will not go through Entity Framework, I may use some of its optimistic concurrency framework to store or compare original values). So I am using POCOs to represent my object model, like so...

```
Partial Public Class FS_Item
   Public Property ItemNumber As String
   Public Property ItemDescription As String
   Public Property ItemUM As String
   ' zillions more properties
   Private _ItemInventories As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory) = New HashSet(Of FS_ItemInventory)
   Public Overridable Property ItemInventories As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory)
      Get
         Return _ItemInventories
      End Get
      Friend Set(value As ICollection(Of FS_ItemInventory))
         _ItemInventories = value
      End Set
   End Property

End Class
```

I have a RESTful API implemented with ApiController-derived classes like so...

```
Public Class FSItemController
   Inherits ApiController

   Private data As New FSDB()

   ' GET api/fsitem
   Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of FS_Item)
      Return data.FS_Item.Take(50).ToArray()
   End Function

   ' Etc...

   ' POST api/fsitem
   Public Sub PostValue(ByVal value As IEnumerable(Of FS_Item))
      ' Not implemented yet
   End Sub
End Class
```

And following the SPA example code for the Todo list application, I have a client side datacontext which can post data, which I'm considering doing from a grid control like so...

```
window.webui = window.webui || {};

window.webui.inventorycontext = (function () {
    var datacontext = {
        getItems: getItems,
        getItem: getItem,
        getNextItem: getNextItem,
        saveItems: saveItems
    };
    return datacontext;

    function getItems(itemsObservable, errorObservable) {
        return ajaxRequest("get", inventoryUrl())
            .done(getSucceeded)
            .fail(getFailed);
       // ...
    }

    // ...

    function saveItems(items, errorObservable) {
        return ajaxRequest("post", inventoryUrl(), items)
            .done(postSucceeded)
            .fail(postFailed);

        function postSucceeded(data) {
           // Not implemented yet
        }

        function postFailed() {
            errorObservable("Error saving items.");
        }
    }

    function ajaxRequest(type, url, data, dataType) { // Ajax helper
        var options = {
            dataType: dataType || "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: type,
            data: data ? ko.toJSON(data) : null
        };
        var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
        if (antiForgeryToken) {
            options.headers = {
                'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
            }
        }
        return $.ajax(url, options);
    }
    // routes
    function inventoryUrl(id) { return "/api/FSItem/" + (id || ""); }
    function inventoryNextUrl(id, next) { return "/api/FSItem/" + (id || "") + "?nextItem=" + next; }
})();
```

The grid is based on the SlickGrid, and the data coming from is is extracted by a `save` function in the `.viewmodel.js` file like so...

```
self.save = function () {
    grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit();
    var items = grid.getData().getItems();
    datacontext.saveItems(items, error);
};
```

BTW, I'm also using knockout for data binding, and I have included jQuery and elements of jquery-ui.

I'm having great success at reading values, changing values and posting the whole array back to the server and seeing the updates in a debugger, but have not yet figured out an optimal way to persist them safely.

Finally to my question. I have read that there is a convention of which knockoutjs and possibly other frameworks are aware where adding a `_destroy` property or something to deleted objects will treat it as deleted so server code can become aware of its removal. And I suspect there might be some similar convention for dealing with updated objects using optimistic concurrency, but even if there is, I'm not clear on how this information would make it back the the server because my object model on the server side does not include properties like _destroy or other objects, and adding them would probably stray from POCO ideals, right?

What's the right way to ensure that the updated objects being submitted by the client have not changed since they were last accessed. I can probably figure out my own way to track original and new values on the client if one doesn't already exist (although I'd be interested to know about what mechanisms may already exist). But I'm stumped in how that information would be communicated back to the ApiController without polluting the POCO objects. Has anyone implemented optimistic concurrency with this set of frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new class in my controller:

```
Public Class PostedFS_ItemData
   Public Property originals As FS_Item()
   Public Property updated As FS_Item()
End Class
```

And updated my Post method:

```
Public Sub PostValue(ByVal value As PostedFS_ItemData)
   'Not implemented yet
End Sub
```

Now I think I can map originals rows to updated rows based on the key values, which are required.